# Cómo cortar un email guardado en un String en c#?

Tags: c#

Necesito recortar una variable String que guarda un correo,  hola@example.com de tal manera que guarde o quede solo hola y borre o elimine el @example.com pensé en usar substring pero este divide por la cantidad de caracteres y en un correo electrónico el tamaño puede variar.
Agradezco de antemano.

Comment: con split('@')   y entonces el primer valor de el areglo seria lo que necesitas

Comment: es lo que tenes que usar.. lo que pasa es que ademas, deberias buscar donde esta la arroba.. algo como.. indexof....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C# puedes utilizar la sentencia .split, que funciona de la siguiente manera, imagina tenemos una cadena de la siguiente forma:

```
//cadena a separar
string cadena = "Hola, tiempo sin verte, ¿como estas?";
//llenando arreglo con la cadena, separando por el delimitador, en este caso por cada coma (',')
string[] palabras = cadena.Split(',');
//arreglo que contiene los elementos [0]= "Hola" [1] = " tiempo sin verte" [2] = " ¿como estas?"
foreach (string palabra in palabras)
{
    //imprimiendo los elementos
    Console.WriteLine(palabra);
}
```

en tu caso tu delimitador seria el @ para poder hacerlo con los correos electrónicos :)

Comment: Entiendo te agradezco.

Comment: Me alegra :) recuerda mandar como correctas y puntuar +1 las respuestas que den solución a la problemática que planteas en tu pregunta